# Erro na hora de retornar um vetor char

Tags: array, arduino, return, char

Estou tentando fazer uma função que lê um arquivo .json e retorna o conteudo. Apesar da leitura bem sucedida, na hora retornar ou imprimi na serial, apresenta-se alguns caracteres a mais " @⸮4!@". Alguem poderia me ajudar a resolver?
No arquivo .json
`[{"nome":"Julio","sobrenome":"Carvalho","senha":"123","id":0}]`
Na função de leitura

```
File users = SPIFFS.open("/users.json" , "r");
    if(!users){Serial.println("file open failed");}
    Serial.println(users.available());
    char usuarios[users.available()];
    for (int aux=0; users.available(); aux++){
      Serial.println(users.available());
      usuarios[aux] = char(users.read());
      Serial.println(usuarios[aux]);
    }   
    Serial.println(users.available());
    users.close();
    Serial.print(usuarios);
    return usuarios;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, bastou passar a variavel `char usuarios[users.available()]` para `String usuarios`. Isso provavelmente estava acontecendo pela variavel em char não ter o tamanho correto e armazenar lixo de memoria nas posições exedentes.